# fiddler post + webapi 2 issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

This is my webapi 2 endpoint - the MVC duplicate suggestion is not relevant

```
[Route("Test2")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test2([FromBody] Guid? guid)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

when I use fiddler to manually test this using:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

in the header and this payload in the body:

```
{"guid":"1c3c8edc-d87a-46dc-adbf-e7112bf16d22"}
```

The method is hit but the guid is null. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen MVC and WebApi have totally different life cycles. Your suggestion does not belong here!

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen - please remove your duplicate suggestion - this is a webapi 2 not a mvc question!

Comment: My bad with the flag , but i think the mindset around the MVC and WebAPI are not so different , and here if you Knew the MVC life cycle certain;ly you would a possible solution quickly. Like Model Binder.

Comment: Yes I took this on board and try to implement a dedicated model binder - although I am surprised that webapi does not handle this out of the box. Still I think you duplicate suggestion is irrelevant.

Comment: Naturally doens't works like MVC but is simmilar,  see this link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Yes but this is a question about webapi! so please remove this. Besides the answer by marcinax seems to help.

Comment: sure, whatever you want, LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be deserialized directly to `Guid`. Now, you are sending object from fiddler, something like:

```
public class SampleObject
{
     public Guid guid {get; set;}
}
```

Try send just:

```
"1c3c8edc-d87a-46dc-adbf-e7112bf16d22"
```

in the body of the request.

Answer (score 1):

You send response through header. Thats why you get null. You have to send request through body.

```
public class Test
{
 public Guid guid {get; set;}
}
```

you have to sent request through body like

```
"1c3c8edc-d87a-46dc-adbf-e7112bf16d22"
```

and if you want to send request through header then your code will be like this

```
[Route("Test2")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test2()
{
   IEnumerable<string> headerValues=request.Headers.GetValues("MyCustomID");
   var guid = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
   return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think I send this though a header - please read the question - i explicitly say that I put the payload into the body!

Comment: I think it might be helpful for you. Thats why I tell you both way. But it goes in a wrong way. Sorry to disturb you :)